# Setting values from a TextField

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

I´m developing some sort of .csv reader/editor. To do so, I created a class (PersonData) with a fileReader method (importPersonData) that parses the data from a CSV file and creates the variables and its corresponding getters and setters. The program shows the values in the UI in a TextField so that the user can edit them. I want the program to change the value in the PersonData class upon clicking "**Save**" button, but I can´t figure out how. This is what the main class looks like (I omitted the UI parts for simplicity):

```
public class GUI extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
    List<PersonData> people = new ArrayList<PersonData>();

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        File getPersonData = new File ("personData.csv");
        String personDataPath  = getPersonData.getAbsolutePath();
        PersonData.importPersonData(personDataPath,people);

        int dataSize=people.size();
        TextField personNametf[] = new TextField[dataSize];

        int n=0;
        for(PersonData p: people){
            Label personNameLabel = new Label("Name: ");
            //call personName getter and set is as default text field
            personNametf[n] = new TextField(p.getPersonName());
}

    saveButton = new Button("Save");
    saveButton.setOnAction(this);

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        if (actionEvent.getSource()==saveButton){
            int n=0;
            for (PersonData p: people) {
                p.setPersonName(personNametf[n].getText());
            n=n+1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that I can´t use personNametf in the ActionListener method because it belongs to a different method. I can´t declare it at a class level either because the array is empty at this point. I thought about using binded properties, but don´t really know how to work it out.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Just make the text field array an instance variable:

```
public class GUI extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
    List<PersonData> people = new ArrayList<PersonData>();

    private TextField[] personNametf ;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        File getPersonData = new File ("personData.csv");
        String personDataPath  = getPersonData.getAbsolutePath();
        PersonData.importPersonData(personDataPath,people);

        int dataSize=people.size();
        personNametf = new TextField[dataSize];

        int n=0;
        for(PersonData p: people){
            Label personNameLabel = new Label("Name: ");
            //call personName getter and set is as default text field
            personNametf[n++] = new TextField(p.getPersonName());
        }

        saveButton = new Button("Save");
        saveButton.setOnAction(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        if (actionEvent.getSource()==saveButton){
            int n=0;
            for (PersonData p: people) {
                p.setPersonName(personNametf[n].getText());
                n=n+1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The event handler can't be invoked without the save button being displayed, so the `start()` method is guaranteed to be invoked before the event handler. Thus you're guaranteed that the array is initialized before you access it in the event handler.